# SQLITE 3 install error

Tags: python, node.js, sqlite

I'm a total noob on trying to install things through Command line.  I recently installed Node (the most recent version, under version id 9.20).  I am in the middle of trying to install /setup GECKO for auto trading.  And it requires installing SQLite3.  I'm following the directions to setup gecko from this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R68IwVujju8

And I'm at the step where you type from the command line :  npm = install

However after it starts downloading some files it reaches several "ERR!" statements and cuts off.  Here is the output:

(P. S.  I have tried using just "npm install"  and I've tried using "npm install sqlite3", both are give the same errors in the end.

C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable>npm install sqlite3

> sqlite3@3.1.13 install C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v3.1.13/node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.13 and node@9.2.0 (node-v59 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )

C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64 --msvs_version=2017 )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64 --msvs_version=2017 )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\fable187\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64" "--msvs_version=2017"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64 --msvs_version=2017' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.38
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v59-win32-x64 --msvs_version=2017' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.13 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.13 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fable187\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-03T08_00_31_371Z-debug.log

C:\Users\fable187\Downloads\gekko-stable\gekko-stable>

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite3 is not yet compatible with the NodeJS V9.2.0 (have a look at the issue: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/902).

You need to downgrade your nodeJS version to the V8.9.3.

**Tips:** To easly change your node version you can use NVM for Windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

**Python issue:** It's due to "npm install" which is trying to compile (with python) the sources located in node-v59-win32-x64.tar.gz. Because Python is not setup on your computer, you've an error.

Answer (score 0):

Install sqlite3 for nodejs using this command `npm install https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/tarball/master`

Comment: melson mascarenhas, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)